# esbuild failed: word unexpected (expecting ")")

Tags: elixir, esbuild

I was preparing a Docker image for my umbrella elixir application.
I am using `esbuild` for assets compilation.
`esbuild` is installed using as `npm` package.

Dockerfile:

```
# copy umbrella app
COPY ./apps/gpanel ./apps/gpanel

...

# compile assets
RUN mix assets.deploy
```

I got this error:

```bash
/app/apps/gpanel/assets/node_modules/esbuild/bin/esbuild: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /app/apps/gpanel/assets
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node esbuild.js --deploy
```

Answer (score 8):

After some googling, I found that this is a cross-platform build incompatibility problem.

The root cause is that the `node_modules` folder was copied from my dev environment to the docker context.

Adding `node_modules` to `.dockerignore` solved the problem.

Comment: I had this issue in a monorepo - I needed to add `**/node_modules` to `.dockerignore` as well